# destory token after logout

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to destroy auth token when user get logged out. User get logged out successfully in the view that I have provided.But I need to destroy token when user get logout.

```
views.py
```

````
class UserLoginViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self,request):
        try:
            data=request.data
            email=data.get('email')
            password=data.get('password')
            date_of_birth=data.get('date_of_birth')
            if not all([email,password,date_of_birth]):
                raise Exception('all fields are mandetory')

            user=authenticate(username=email,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                token=generate_token()
                user_info=MyUser.objects.get(email=email)
                data=({
                    'email':user_info.email,
                    'password':user_info.password,
                    #'data_of_birth':user_info.data_of_birth
                })
                return Response({"message": "You are successfully logged in",
                "user_info":data,"token": token, "success": True},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            else :
                raise Exception('not authorised')

        except Exception as error:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    def delete(self,request):
        logout(request)
        return Response({'successfull':True})```

#my user is logging out correctly,but i want to doi this by deleting token
````

Comment: What kind of token are you using? JWT?

Comment: i am using outh2

Comment: And are you using the django-oauth-toolkit and the bearer token?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
class UserLoginViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self,request):
        try:
            data=request.data
            email=data.get('email')
            password=data.get('password')
            date_of_birth=data.get('date_of_birth')
            if not all([email,password,date_of_birth]):
                raise Exception('all fields are mandetory')

            user=authenticate(username=email,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                token=generate_token()
                user_info=MyUser.objects.get(email=email)
                data=({
                    'email':user_info.email,
                    'password':user_info.password,
                    #'data_of_birth':user_info.data_of_birth
                })
                return Response({"message": "You are successfully logged in",
                "user_info":data,"token": token, "success": True},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            else :
                raise Exception('not authorised')

        except Exception as error:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class LogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
        logout(request)
        return Response({"message": "success", 'code': status.HTTP_200_OK, 'detail': "logout success"})
```

In app urls.py add new url:

```
path('logout/',LogoutView.as_view()),
```

Comment: But you need to pass auth token to get logout

Comment: lass LogoutViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
        logout(request)
        return Response({"message": "success", 'code': status.HTTP_200_OK, 'detail': "logout success"})

Comment: router.register(r'logout',LogoutViewSet,basename='UserEmailViewSet') #my urls

Comment: from rest_framework import routers
from attempt.views import *
from django.conf.urls import url

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'test', UserViewSet,basename='UserViewSet')
router.register(r'login', UserLoginViewSet,basename='UserLoginViewSet')
router.register(r'email', OrderViewSet,basename='UserEmailViewSet')
router.register(r'logout',LogoutViewSet,basename='UserEmailViewSet')
router.register(r'order',OrderViewSet,basename='OrderViewSet')
urlpatterns = router.urls

Comment: don't use router.register on logout. Remove logout view from router.register and add that url that i have provided

Comment: just do this in your app ```urls.py``` ```from django.urls import path
``` ```path('logout/',LogoutView.as_view()),```

Comment: I am not using viewsets, I am using APIView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206826/discussion-between-merin-and-ashutosh-mishra).